# AVCapture is hanging on release mode in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, video, video-recording

I was developed a on screen video recording app. It will take a video while tapping button. When ever I run on device by debugging mode it’s working fine. But when I take a build on release mode video capturing is hanging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats weird, because basically test flight does nothing with your IPA you can just upload and distribute using test flight . But couple of things need to be checked :

1. Make sure you are uploading latest .ipa file .(Just remove all the ipa files from the organiser and create new one again).
2. Make sure app is uploaded right and you are getting new url from the test flight .